# Filtering a DateField Object Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I've read a whole bunch of similar Stackoverflows on this issue, however my issue seems to be more specific. I can't get the date to display in anyway but the default.

Here is the model in question:

```
class Blog (models.Model):
    ...
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

It's then passed to the template like so, as part of the objects included in Blog.objects.all():

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:10:-1],
    })
```

So currently in my templates, I can display the DateField info by writing the following in a template, as posted is a property of the object :

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.posted }}
{% endfor %}
```

And if I do it that way it displays the date in a rather ugly: 2014-02-24

**How can I change this display?**

Things that I have already tried:

- `{{ post.posted|date:"D M j Y" }}` this displays as empty
- `{{post.posted|date }}` with the settings.py including a `DATE_FORMAT =
  'D M j Y'` this also just displays as empty
- various combinations of `USEL10N = False USEL10N = True` ... still just displays blank

The documentation for 1.6 makes it sound really simple with the "|date" filter, but its just not working on my end. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: In one example you use ``"D M j Y"`` and in another ``'D M J Y'``. Make sure the *j* is lowercase since the uppercase *J* is not listed as [a valid date format character](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Comment: Oh thank you. It is just a typo here though, not in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to test this right now, but something in the docs caught my eye.

The [documentation for the date template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) says

> if value is a datetime object (e.g., the result of datetime.datetime.now()), the output will be the string 'Wed 09 Jan 2008'.

Whereas the [documentation for the `DateField` model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) states that the field contains

> a date, represented in Python by a datetime.date instance.

Could it be that the `date` template filter doesn't take a `datetime.date` instance as its argument? Try and change the Blog model's posted field to a `DateTimeField` and see what happens.

Comment: Just what I was thinking :)

Comment: thank you! thankfully south made the db migration easy.